python muliprocessing: AttributeError: Can't get attribute <function_name> on module
The following code:
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import multiprocessing, itertools, timeit
from functools import partial

processes = 5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(f'processes: {processes}')
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)

def calc(x, y):
   return x+y

def calc_all():
   pairs = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
   results = pool.map(calc, pairs)
   print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   calc_all()

is returning:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
           ^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 389, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'calc' on <module '__main__' from '/workspaces/calc.py'>

If i move just the main to a separate file and import calc_all, i still get the same error (different module name ofcourse)
I'f i move calc_all and the main to another module and import calc, it works fine.
I would like to understand why this is happening when both are top level functions. Is there a better way to solve this problem rather than having to move part of the module to a separate file?

You're starting a pool directly in __main__, so you're starting a pool in each worker process too.  Bad idea.

processes = 5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()  wishful thinking :-)

the intended code is not cpu bound, but heavily i/o bound...so alot of indeterminate waiting there for 1000s of requests

If you're IO-bound not CPU-bound, you should probably use a thread pool not a process pool. Way less overhead.

i will test with that approach. thanks

@wim, are you referring to the asyncio libraries for threading?

No. asyncio is not threading (it's coroutines all in main thread). I was more referring to e.g. ThreadPoolExecutor.

ok...thx.  i've been reading up on it and it seems some argue the performance is pretty good for these type of operations in python.

@wim you are right ThreadpoolExecutor is pretty efficient and simpler (as long as everything is kept thread local).  there are occasions where it does take almost 10 x longer though..not quite sure why...maybe a temp thread or db lock...
anyway thanks for pointing me to the documentation. im learning..

I'm not able to replicate it, I get into a weird loop. When asking questions like these, you need to include what your environment is: python version, OS, etc.
Also there's no point in spawning 5*cpu_count processes, that's just gonna create a ton of overhead.
It works fine when I clean it up:
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing, itertools, timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def setup():
    processes =  multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print(f'processes: {processes}')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)
    return pool

def calc(args):
   return sum(args)

def calc_all():
    pool = setup()
    pairs = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
    results = pool.map(calc, pairs)
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   calc_all()


my dev environment is a vscode environment based on the python3.12 image, which i believe is bookworm.

interesting but just that change with pool solved the issue. i understand the bad code i had and that that may cause each process to spawn its own pool..but even so, why would that cause the exception i saw?

and regarding the process count. i tested various iterations of splitting the data and pools, and at creating 3-5*cpu count, and splitting the requests (db requests) (about 400-1000) into that number, seems to yield the best performance so far.  obviously i'll have to performance tune when i get it up to the cloud

It is important not to create the pool at module global, it needs to be guarded inside __name__ == "__main__" somehow so that the worker processes don't also create a pool when importing the module.
For the call, you can use starmap:
import multiprocessing


def calc(x, y):
   return x+y

def calc_all(pool):
   pairs = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
   results = pool.starmap(calc, pairs)
   print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
       calc_all(pool)


thanks, in the actual code, when passing just the split list i use map. down further im passing the list with another set of parameters and there i use starmap.  i need to refresh on what the benefits of just always using  starmap is
